# How to get demographics data on Json object

Tags: facebook, json, facebook-graph-api, import, facebook-insights

I'm trying to import the **insights** data as **json** object, but there are some of the data doesn't retrieved on the json object like "**Organic shares**" and "**Demographics**" data. Any ideas how  could I retrieve this data to be able to display it on my application ?

Here is how I import the data from facebook: https://graph.facebook.com/Domain_ID/insights/?access_token= ?????????????

Answer (score 0):

You can run an FQL statement via the Graph API looking for `page_impressions_organic`, `page_posts_impressions_organic`, `page_posts_impressions_organic_unique`, `post_impressions_organic`, `post_impressions_organic_unique`, `page_fans_gender_age`, etc.

See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/

Comment: Thanks DMCS for your help, I tried to use the matrix elements you mentioned, but it returns an empty data while there is data appears on the Facebook.